# Pycharm - Changing theme for Navigation pane?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have selected a dark theme for Pycharm to keep it easier on the eyes when coding. However the Navigation pane on the left side is still in bright white and distracts from coding.

Is there a way to change the theme for that part as well?  I can't find any thing in the settings.

Thanks a lot

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible out of the box without changing the Java Look&Feel, there is an [open feature request to make it configurable](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-62247) and one user has [contributed a plug-in](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/index?pr=idea&pluginId=7055) making the background dark.

Comment: The solution that Daniele De Francesco made work with his dark-IDEA.png is exactly what I need. A pity he doesn't explain the steps. I couldn't find the plug-in you mentioned there. Though, could you point me to it please?

Comment: Added plug-in link to the answer.

Comment: Thats great, Thank you. Once I downloaded the jar file, how do I load it into PyCharm? Simply execute the file? I couldn't find anything on their Wiki section. :)

Comment: You should install it from `Settings` | `Plugins`, either from the repository or by selecting the downloaded file.